# is there any android java code to stop movement of GPS location when device is at same location?

Tags: android

I am developing Vehicle tracking app and we are using drivers GPS to get location.

I am using Google periodic location update code with 5 seconds interval.

When driver stays at one point for about 2 minutes and more GPS location is moving from here and there so the poly line which i am drawing is not smooth its creating mess over that point.

So any body can guide me how can i avoid getting the fake location from device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This function will send the location when your device is ideal.

```
   LocationCallback mHistoryIdealLocationCallback;  

  private void requestHistoryUpdates() {
        try {
            LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
            request.setInterval(10 * 60 * 1000);
            request.setFastestInterval(10 * 60 * 1000);
            request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            clientHistoryIdeal = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mHistoryIdealLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                    }
                };
                clientHistoryIdeal.requestLocationUpdates(request, mHistoryIdealLocationCallback, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also manage your live location with **Smallest Displacement with 10 Meters**:

```
LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
            request.setInterval(10 * 1000);
            request.setFastestInterval(10 * 1000);
            request.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.getSpeed()` when user is not moving then your function is not running or Polyline is not drawn on the screen

you can use like this.

```
if(location.getSpeed()>=20){
//Write you condition
}
```

Another solution is, in this formula you can check displacement and perform your task as well

```
 public static double displacement(LatLng start, LatLng end) {
  try {
    Location location1 = new Location("locationA");
    location1.setLatitude(start.latitude);
    location1.setLongitude(start.longitude);
    Location location2 = new Location("locationA");
    location2.setLatitude(end.latitude);
    location2.setLongitude(end.longitude);

    double distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    DecimalFormatSymbols custom = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    custom.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(custom);
    return Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(distance));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Utils.LogExceptionToFabric(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. If you observe the above image i uploaded , where while the vehicle is on Road , location provider is giving some other co-ordinates which about to 50 meter away from the exact location. So event if I check displacement my logic will accept that new co-ordinate even if it is fake.

Comment: In MI phone i am not getting the exact location through fusedLocationProvider. Is There are any settings to get accurate location.

Comment: Yes you are right but before you can check location.getspeed()>30 in if condition